# Send Default data through ajax post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-post

I am trying to send a default data in every ajax post request however using the below code I the data is being sent for all the requests. Please suggest.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
          data: {
             at: $('#at').attr('value'),
          },
       });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try below. Thought not tried it running.

1. Setup the ajax like below with "beforeSetup"

   ```
   $.ajaxSetup({
       beforeSend: myFunc
   });
   ```
2. In the function "myFunc" check if it is a post request then set the data.

UPDATE : This will work !

```
$.ajaxSetup({
                  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                          if (settings.type == 'POST') {
                                  if(settings.data == null || settings.data == '' || settings.data == undefined) {
                                          settings.data = "?value=test";
                                  } else {
                                          settings.data = settings.data + "&value=test";
                                  }
                          }
                  }
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register a global AJAX event handler like [`.ajaxSend()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) and check the request type, for example

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqxhr, settings) {
    if (settings.type == 'POST' && !settings.data) {
        settings.data = $.param({at: $('#at').attr('value')});
    }
});
```

Comment: But the data is now being shown in the console or even the request.

Comment: @user3115056 I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.